# golang with master detail mysql entities

Tags: mysql, go

I have been playing around with GO programming language. I am looking for some help on how to set up master detail entities. 
in c#, I would do below. I have seen many example in GO that deals with one table. but I could not find any example that deals with master detail entities like this.

GO seems very different than C# and Java. If this is not the right way to do it, please explain or point me to some example how I can achieve similar functionality in GO.

Thank you!

```
public class Employee
{
    public int id{get; set;}
    public string lastName{get; set;}
    public string firstName{get; set;}
    public Collection<Address> addresses { get; set; }    
}

public class Address
{
    public int id{get; set;}
    public string street{get; set;}
    public string zip{get; set;} 
    public virtual Employee employee{get; set;}    
}
```

Comment: I think [GORM](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) is what you want. It's one of famous ORM in Go.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I reviewed GORM. I can learn many things for this. At this time I am exploring more on hand written sql.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an *Object Relationnal Mapper*. There is a lot of ORMs written in Golang, but they have limitations compared to libraries written in more dynamic languages due to the language itself.

You could also writte your SQL statements by hand, which is often simpler and faster than using an ORM.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am looking for best practice example on how to do master detail relationship with hand written sql and without using ORM. I reviewed http://go-database-sql.org/ and it has pretty god tutorial but I could not find master detail example.

Comment: I think what you call *master detail relationship* is a term specific to your C# ORM for a child entity. I think the wikipedia page on [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) is a good starting place to get insights on this matter.